# Sitefinity responsive mail with zurb framework

Tags: css, email, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, sitefinity

Using the [zurb framework](http://zurb.com/ink/), I want to make a responsive newsletter with Sitefinity ECM. When I make a email with the css in it (like [this screenshot](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dave-Paul/folders/Jing/media/f645b91f-fa9b-4137-84da-b0c11437c42e/2013-12-24_1100.png)) and the code is here: http://pastebin.com/6gaSNKXT.

That code is pasted in a [message template](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dave-Paul/folders/Jing/media/a1c3f7f7-ea97-449c-bc56-81a50883a8ef/2013-12-24_1106.png) and used for a new test newsletter. In the preview mode it is responsive, but in gmail isn't the css loaded and in hotmail the css is loaded but isn't responsive. Also on my IDevice, it is not responsive.

How can I use zurb framework with Sitefinity for sending an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail strips the `<style>` tag, so you'll need to inline your CSS first. The Zurb Ink framework requires you to take this step before sending the email. This might also fix your other issues - hard to tell at this point.

I think Ink has a built in CSS inliner, which may not be applicable if you are running through Sitefinity. Here is a list of [css inlining tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code/17882057#17882057) that may come in handy - I don't think any of them have an API, so you'll probably have to inline the template before the user wysiwyg's their content in there from Sitefinity.